# Python remove first number from string if it's 0

Tags: python, string

I'm getting a string from a form format `07123456789` (it's a phone number) and I would like to remove the first number/character only if it's a zero. And after that add `44` in front. So the output will be `447123456789`.

Which is the best way to do it?

Comment: You should really add `+44` to the front. Otherwise you cannot distinguish betewen phone numbers which started to have no `0`, but a `44` at the start. (I suppose adding the `44` should only happen if there was a `0`, otherwise not.)

Comment: Im using an API to send text messages. The accepted format of number is 447123456789.

Comment: Ok. But what happens (or: what should happen) if the number didn't start with `0` at the first place? Is it supposed to contain the prefix already or is it an error case?

Comment: the form that Im requesting the number has validation rules and will always starts with zero. Actually here I converting the local number to an international accepted number for the API. I would like the user to type his number as local to be much easier for him.

Comment: Ok, then all is fine. I just stumbled over your "I would like to remove the first number/character only if its a zero" part and wondered what would happen when it is *not* a zero. BTW, with these restrictions you disallow entering numbers from abroad. That may or may not be wanted, just wanted to point out...

Comment: On my project I allow only numbers from the UK and USA at the moment, With the answers I've got from here, I managed to get the result I need from both cases. Thanks for your interest though, I'll keep your thoughts for later, when I will need to expand my project to accept numbers from more countries.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `str.startswith`

```
In [11]: s = '07123456789'

In [12]: '44{}'.format(s[1:] if s.startswith('0') else s)
Out[12]: '447123456789'
```

Also, instead of `format`ting, you can join the strings together with `+` operator:

```
'44' + (s[1:] if s.startswith('0') else s)
```

If you're sure there's at most 1 zero at the beginning of the number, you can safely use `str.lstrip` or `int` conversion (see other answers).

Answer (score 5):

We can convert string into integer e.g.

```
>>> s = "07123456789"
>>> "44%s"%(int(s))
'447123456789'
```

We can use lstrip method of string which will remove all "0" from left of string. e.g.

```
>>> "44%s"%(s.lstrip("0"))
'447123456789'
```

If we want to consider only the first character from string then we can try following: 
(above two solution will not when more then one "0" at starting of string.)

```
>>> if s[0]=="0":
...   s = s[1:]
... 
>>> "44%s"%s
'447123456789'
```

Or go with solution from jamylak

```
>>> s = '07123456789'
>>> "44%s%s"%(s[0].strip("0"), s[1:])
'447123456789'
```

Comment: I like `lstrip` in this case. seems like the exact tool for the job

Comment: @jamylak not when the phone number has more than one `0` at the beginning... I removed the lstrip from my answer for this very reason.

Comment: I thought about that, then i thought the phone numbers probably don't have more than 1 `0` but that's being naiive

Comment: yes, `lstrip` and `int` are not work when string has more than one `"0"` at the beginning, it will remove all `"0"` from the beginning.

Answer (score 4):

Just another possible option:

```
>>> s = '07123456789'
>>> '44' + s[0].strip('0') + s[1:]
'447123456789'
```

Answer (score 3):

`str.lstrip` is best for this case:

```
>>> s = '07123456789'
>>> '44'+s.lstrip('0')
'447123456789'
>>> s = '7123456789'
>>> '44'+s.lstrip('0')
'447123456789'
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to go about this is to cast to `int` to remove the zero at the beginning and then cast back to a `str`:

```
s = '07123456789'
s = '44'+str(int(s))
```

Comment: Plus 1. More general approach than using `startswith`, probably.

Comment: This will remove all the leading zeroes, while he asked for the first one.